# sql select with 'where' in another table

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I want to get some rows in table A based on a true or false select on table B.

TABLE A

```
id    event     name
4585  meeting   calendar discussion
```

TABLE B

```
id    idevent   date
534   4585      15/02/2015
535   4585      16/02/2015
536   4585      17/02/2015
537   4585      18/02/2015
538   4585      19/02/2015
```

I want to select only the event in the table A that its in certain range date on the table B

something like

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE date > today in tableB
```

Comment: Use a [`JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html)

Comment: if i use join i will get the line in table a repeated for which line of table b

Comment: @lambaoalfaex can you update your question to add the JOIN query that you tried and the one that is not working ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 i tried so many thing already that i deleted everything and i came to ask on stack XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b
ON a.id = b.idevent AND b.date > CURRENT_DATE
```

Just a couple remarks on other methods proposed:

Using `EXISTS` is probably preferable to `IN`, but Postgres might treat them as equivalent anyway.  I know in SQL Server that happens sometimes - the only other issue would be if b.date is NULLABLE, which could cause unexpected behavior when using `IN`.

Using your condition in the `ON` condition instead of the `WHERE` clause is better because it will help the engine know to exclude rows before returning them to run the `WHERE` filter.

I'm using `DISTINCT` here because otherwise, this query would return the same row from `table_a` each time there was a match in `table_b` with a `date` greater than today.  Another option would be to use `GROUP BY` instead, if you wanted to do some aggregate reporting, such as `GROUP BY a.id, a.event, a.name`.  However, since you're not doing any aggregate reporting (like the count of events on particular day or something), `DISTINCT` should get the job done more clearly and quickly.

Comment: This will return a row for every record in `table_b` not the single record from `table_a` ... unless you add `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`; e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT table_a.* ... `

Comment: Why not just use `WHERE` for the date comparison? The "engine" can optimize this by itself.

Comment: @alexis explained in answer - it's generally better to limit the join rather than limit the results of the join if possible

Comment: I'm not 100% certain how PostGRES's query optimizer works but this *should* be about the most efficient way to run the query I think.

Comment: Hi @DanField with your method i can get the same result as the solution from Gordon.
and using "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" with several tests the difference on the total runtime was very small.
I save both suggestion on my SQL resources.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You can use EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB
              WHERE TableA.id = TableB.idevent
                    AND TableB.Date>current_date)
```

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use `in`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.idEvent IN (SELECT idEvent FROM tableB b WHERE b.date > current_date);
```

Comment: Hi @gordon-linoff
Your solution fits me great, i didn't know about IN, but just help me understand something, i searched on the postgres manual, but is not clear.
I have one id Checking against 5 others ids, so i think that he's doing this.
    id 4585 ( false )
    id 4585 ( true )
    id 4585 ( true )
    id 4585 ( false )
    id 4585 ( true )

why the use of IN dont repeat the line like EXISTS  or JOIN ?

Comment: @lambaoalfaex . . . Neither `EXISTS` nor `IN` produce duplicate lines because they are in the `WHERE` clause.  `JOIN` can produce duplicates when there are multiple matches between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `JOIN` you can do this:

```
SELECT 
     *
FROM 
     tableA
JOIN 
     tableB ON (tableA.id = tableB.idevent)
WHERE 
     tableB.date > YOUR_TODAY_DATE;
```

Comment: Is the same method, i just started to wrote my answer before anyone posted, when i finished i just saw the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

try this request

```
Select Current_date AS today , event 
from A,B
where A.id = B.idevent
and B.date > today
```

today will take current system date 
u can check this link for more informations:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Does postgres have GETDATE()?

Comment: No , in postgres there is current_date instead !

Comment: Then you should change it.  This question is tagged postgres, not sql server.